# UIWebView : Trap intermediate calls made by UIWebView

Tags: ios

I am opening a URL using the UIWebView. The Java script that runs in UIWebView makes intermediate requests, Is there any way to get information on these requests and responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIWebViewDelegate method webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: will let you inspect all the requests for a UIWebView before they are made.